# How to use a CDN inside a React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js, cdn

I'm trying to use a library built on D3, called Greuler, in order to dynamically render graphs. The NPM  package for it seems to be broken. When I switched out for the Greuler CDN, the test graph inside my index.html finally worked.

However, I'm working on a React app, and I want the graph to be rendered from a React component. Here the problem comes up: the react component doesn't use the Greuler CDN scripts that are in my index.html, and I've tried multiple ways of running the scripts inside my component, but nothing seems to work.

The two main errors are:

`error  'greuler' is not defined` (in my component)

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getAttribute' of null` (in the D3 code)

My working index.html, with hard-coded graph looks like:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Navigating Spinoza</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.6/d3.js"></script>
    <script src="http://marvl.infotech.monash.edu/webcola/cola.v3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maurizzzio.github.io/greuler/greuler.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <div class="row" id="demo">
      <script>
        var instance = greuler({
          target: '#demo',
          width: 480,
          height: 500,
          data: {
            nodes: [
              {id: 0, label: "E1Def3", r: 25},
              {id: 1, label: "E1P4", r: 15},
              {id: 2, label: "E1P2", r: 15},
              {id: 3, label: "E1P1", r: 15},
              {id: 4, label: "E1P5", r: 15},
              {id: 5, label: "E1P6", r: 25}
            ],
            links: [
              {source: 0, target: 1, directed: true},
              {source: 0, target: 2, directed: true},
              {source: 0, target: 3, directed: true},
              {source: 1, target: 4, directed: true},
              {source: 2, target: 5, directed: true},
              {source: 3, target: 4, directed: true},
              {source: 4, target: 5, directed: true}
            ]
          }
        }).update()
      </script>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

My last desperate attempt at the render function in the component looks like:

```
render() {
    return (
     <div class="row" id="demo">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.6/d3.js"></script>
    <script src="http://marvl.infotech.monash.edu/webcola/cola.v3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maurizzzio.github.io/greuler/greuler.min.js"></script>
     { 
        greuler({
          target: '#demo',
          width: 480,
          height: 500,
          data: {
            nodes: [
              {id: 0, label: "E1Def3", r: 25},
              {id: 1, label: "E1P4", r: 15},
              {id: 2, label: "E1P2", r: 15},
              {id: 3, label: "E1P1", r: 15},
              {id: 4, label: "E1P5", r: 15},
              {id: 5, label: "E1P6", r: 25}
            ],
            links: [
              {source: 0, target: 1, directed: true},
              {source: 0, target: 2, directed: true},
              {source: 0, target: 3, directed: true},
              {source: 1, target: 4, directed: true},
              {source: 2, target: 5, directed: true},
              {source: 3, target: 4, directed: true},
              {source: 4, target: 5, directed: true}
            ]
          }
        }).update()
      }
    </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best/simplest solution would be to have a stub index.html file which includes the scripts that you need (you could install libraries from npm as others has suggested, however this will work for libraries which only have a CDN). Thus you would have an `index.html` file like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Navigating Spinoza</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.6/d3.js"></script>
    <script src="http://marvl.infotech.monash.edu/webcola/cola.v3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maurizzzio.github.io/greuler/greuler.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <div class="row" id="demo"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

And then a react component like like this (I have moved some code around to better follow some react idioms):

```
var Component = React.createClass({    
  componentDidMount:function() {
    greuler({
      target: '#chart',
      width: 480,
      height: 500,
      data: {
        nodes: [
          {id: 0, label: "E1Def3", r: 25},
          {id: 1, label: "E1P4", r: 15},
          {id: 2, label: "E1P2", r: 15},
          {id: 3, label: "E1P1", r: 15},
          {id: 4, label: "E1P5", r: 15},
          {id: 5, label: "E1P6", r: 25}
        ],
        links: [
          {source: 0, target: 1, directed: true},
          {source: 0, target: 2, directed: true},
          {source: 0, target: 3, directed: true},
          {source: 1, target: 4, directed: true},
          {source: 2, target: 5, directed: true},
          {source: 3, target: 4, directed: true},
          {source: 4, target: 5, directed: true}
        ]
      }
    }).update()
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div id="chart"></div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Component />, document.querySelector('root'));
```

This is a simple solution that could stand to do more (such as use react's state and properties to pass around parameters) but this should give a general idea of the solution. This code also assumes that you have included the React and ReactDOM libraries in some way (babel, CDN, etc.).

Comment: it says still greuler is undefined. (actually I am trying to use three.js cdn with react - this should work I think, but it's not.)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Navigating Spinoza</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="root"></div>
<div class="row" id="demo"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.6/d3.js">
</script>
<script src="http://marvl.infotech.monash.edu/webcola/cola.v3.min.js">
</script>
<script src="http://maurizzzio.github.io/greuler/greuler.min.js"></script>
<script>
    import React from 'react'
    import { render } from 'react-dom'

    var Instance = greuler({
      target: '#demo',
      width: 480,
      height: 500,
      data: {
        nodes: [
          {id: 0, label: "E1Def3", r: 25},
          {id: 1, label: "E1P4", r: 15},
          {id: 2, label: "E1P2", r: 15},
          {id: 3, label: "E1P1", r: 15},
          {id: 4, label: "E1P5", r: 15},
          {id: 5, label: "E1P6", r: 25}
        ],
        links: [
          {source: 0, target: 1, directed: true},
          {source: 0, target: 2, directed: true},
          {source: 0, target: 3, directed: true},
          {source: 1, target: 4, directed: true},
          {source: 2, target: 5, directed: true},
          {source: 3, target: 4, directed: true},
          {source: 4, target: 5, directed: true}
        ]
      }
    }).update()

    render(
      <Instance />,
      document.getElementById('root')
    )
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry. My fault. I copied it from my files. I have edit that. Only delete this two lines.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the module with npm:

```
npm install greuler
```

See here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/greuler

Then use in your component:

```
var greuler = require('greuler')
```

Comment: @ toby, i tried two things right now, and neither worked:

`npm i greuler`  with  `var greuler = require('greuler')` throws error `unexpected import statement` (im using `import` for all dependencies); yet, when I write out the complete path to greuler, i.e., `var greuler = require('greuler/dist/greuler.js')` then i get the D3 error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getAttribute' of null`

the exact same pattern happens when i imported/required the bower_component logic after doing `bower install greuler` and requiring or importing (i tried both) the library into my component

Comment: It looks like maybe this library hasn't been converted to es6 yet - I'm not sure what the repercussions of that might be, though. Also, it might not work with the newer version of D3, I'd double-check that before you put too much time in.

Comment: it's weird, it wont work while i just import `from 'greuler'` but it works when i set the full relative path and do what @Jordan Hand suggested

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a **module bundler** like [webpack](https://webpack.github.io/docs/) or [browserify](http://browserify.org/) and then import the library.

`npm install greuler`

`var greuler = require('greuler')`

Answer (score 0):

I got an issue like this, but the old answers cannot run. So I create this here.

Url

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.6/d3.js"></script>
<script src="https://fastly.jsdelivr.net/npm/webcola@3.4.0/WebCola/cola.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://fastly.jsdelivr.net/npm/greuler@1.0.0/dist/greuler.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17.0.2/umd/react.development.js"></script>
```

JS

```
class Component extends React.Component {


componentDidMount() {
    greuler({
    target: '#chart',
    width: 480,
    height: 500,
    data: {
      nodes: [
        {id: 0, label: "E1Def3", r: 25},
        {id: 1, label: "E1P4", r: 15},
        {id: 2, label: "E1P2", r: 15},
        {id: 3, label: "E1P1", r: 15},
        {id: 4, label: "E1P5", r: 15},
        {id: 5, label: "E1P6", r: 25}
      ],
      links: [
        {source: 0, target: 1, directed: true},
        {source: 0, target: 2, directed: true},
        {source: 0, target: 3, directed: true},
        {source: 1, target: 4, directed: true},
        {source: 2, target: 5, directed: true},
        {source: 3, target: 4, directed: true},
        {source: 4, target: 5, directed: true}
      ]
    }
    }).update()
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div id="chart"></div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Component />, document.querySelector('#root'));

console.log(React)
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mango3403/qk98cf0n/32