# How to import unpkg components in react browser

Tags: reactjs, unpkg

I'm using React directly in the browser by importing from unpkg. But when I include the component [`react-pagination-js`](https://github.com/isaurssaurav/react-pagination-js), `Pagination` still remains undefined throughout the rest of the scope.

```
<!-- Note: when deploying, replace "development.js" with "production.min.js". -->
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>

<!-- react-js-pagination -->
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-pagination-js@2.0.0/dist/index.umd.js"></script>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/babel" src="{% static 'js/practice/ChallengeList.js' %}"></script>

<script type="text/babel">
  const e = React.createElement;
  const el = document.querySelector('#challenges-component');
  ReactDOM.render(e(ChallengeList), el);
</script>
```

How do I use `Pagination` in my `ChallengeList` component?

Comment: How have you imported `Pagination` in your `ChallengeList.js` file? Can you share the imported line?

Comment: @ShahnawazHossan I haven't imported it. I just expected all the contents of Pagination to be available globally? Adding `import Pagination from "react-pagination-js"` gives `require` does not exist

Comment: Bro, if you don't install it with npm, you can't `import Pagination from "react-pagination-js"` like this. Did you install the package with npm? Or you would like to use it simply by adding it from the `script` tag?

Comment: @ShahnawazHossan I'm trying to use it with the script tag. It's supposed to be usable with unpkg directly in the browser like React...

Comment: Bro, have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43747443/how-to-use-a-cdn-inside-a-react-component).